# Why stackoverflow's google prettifier works with <body>, <html> e.t.c tags in <code> or <pre> tag?

Tags: html

I asked a question before why the `<code>` tag does not support `<html>, <head>, <body>` tags. But answer I got was that it is not supported. A few days back, in meta.stackoverflow.com, I saw a question about stackoverflow's code highlighter (Some Issue). Someone, answered that it is google prettifier. I noticed it and remembered it. As google prettifier, also recommends to use `<code>` or `<pre>` tags for code prettifying. Then how stackoverflow's code tag support all HTML tags to display it as code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<code>` element does support arbitrary content. You just have to encode the HTML int here, like this:

```
<code>
&lt;html&gt; HTML document &lt;/html&gt;
</code>
```

That's what stackoverflow does if you type

```
<html> HTML document </html>
```

Comment: I will accept answer in 4 minutes. I am fool that I can also use PHP `htmlspecialchars`